# Using Variables in Variable definition

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to get variables into variables but it wont work. I searched google and tried a lot of stuff but it did not wor out.
I hope this question ist not "dumb":
What am I doing wrong ?

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary
Library           OperatingSystem

*** Variable ***
${year}           Get Time    return year
${month}          Get Time    return month
${day}            Get Time    return day
${output}         ${CURDIR}\Testing\Tests\SRV\csdb_@{year}-@{month}-@{day}.log

*** Testcases ***    
Textfile should have a line saying the service is started
    ${errors} =    Grep File    ${output}    Test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [robot framework user's guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-table):

> The most common source for variables are Variable tables in test case
>   files and resource files. Variable tables are convenient, because they
>   allow creating variables in the same place as the rest of the test
>   data, and the needed syntax is very simple. **Their main disadvantages
>   are that values are always strings and they cannot be created
>   dynamically.**

In order to do what you want, you'll need to define the variables in a keyword. For example:

```
*** Keywords ***
Get Output
    ${year}=      Get Time    year
    ${month}=     Get Time    month
    ${day}=       Get Time    day
    ${output}=    Set variable    ${CURDIR}/Testing/Tests/SRV/csdb_${year}-${month}-${day}.log
    [Return]      ${output}


*** Testcases ***    
Textfile should have a line saying the service is started
    ${output}=     Get Output
    ${errors} =    Grep File    ${output}    Test
```

Note:  you can fetch all three parts of the data in a single call to the keyword, like so:

```
${year}  ${month}  ${day}=  Get Time    year month day
```

It's a bit  hard to read with the space-separated format, but the variable names must each be separated by two or more spaces, but "year month day" should have only one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Seems like I need to get a bit more of the basics - i was not sure about the difference betwqeen *** Keywords *** and *** Variables *** but now I know.