# Is there a way to monitor test log for error string using robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

I am a newbie to robot framework, I just wanted to know if i can monitor my application log for a certain keyword i.e. **FAIL**, If i find the message i stop test and report failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the standard keyword `Grep File` might be appropriate. In the built in [Operating System Library documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Grep%20File) you can find more details. In this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772879/using-variables-in-variable-definition/29774308#29774308) an example is given.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Ill take a look into this module.